# Does the square of a prime ideal contain all the polynomials vanishing to second order on its variety?

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry

Let $X \subseteq \mathbb{C}^n$ be an irreducible affine variety and $P \subseteq \mathbb{C}[z_1,\ldots,z_n]$ the corresponding prime ideal. So, by definition, $P$ consists of all the polynomials which vanish on $X$. It follows that all the elements of $P^2$ vanish to (at least) second order on $X$. To be more precise, for any $f \in P^2$, both $f$ and all of its first order partial derivatives vanish on $X$.

**Question:** Does $P^2$ actually contain all of the polynomials that vanish to (at least) second order on $X$, and similarly for higher powers of $P$?

I have a vague suspicion that the answer should be "no", in general, but would be glad learn otherwise.

I had one thought... In differential geometry, we could invoke the tangent bundle $T\mathbb{C}^n = \mathbb{C}^n \times \mathbb{C}^n$ and embed $X$ there as $X'=X\times\{0\}$. Then, a function $f \in C^\infty(\mathbb{C}^n)$ vanishes to second order on $X$ if and only if $Df : T\mathbb{C}^n \to T\mathbb{C}^n$ vanishes on $X'$. Maybe this idea is helpful as it relates second order vanishing on an affine variety to first order vanishing on another affine variety?

Answers accessible to someone (like me) who doesn't know much algebraic geometry and is more comfortable with analysis and differential geometry would be appreciated.

Comment: I think what you want is the second symbolic power of $P$: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_power_of_an_ideal

Comment: @morrowmh: perfect! Thanks for the reference. Apparently the theorem of Nagata-Zariski referenced in the article shows that the $n$th symbolic power $P^{(n)}$ of $P$ exactly equals the polynomials vanishing to order $\geq n$ on $X$. There is also a remark in the second paragraph to the effect that $P^{(n)}$ equals the $P$-primary component of $P^n$. So, I guess $P^n$ coincides with $P^{(n)}$ if and only if $P^n$ is a primary ideal. I know some examples where powers of $P$ are not primary, so those should also be examples where the equality $P^n=P^{(n)}$ fails.